# Unity Click button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to remove a `gameObject` from the world and a list using:

```
   Destroy(obj);
   itemsInInv.Remove(obj.gameObject);
```

But for some reason, it's reading my `list.count` as `0` every time I try to reference it threw a click event. If I use a key down and remove a specific item it works fine. But when I try to read my list threw a click event it returns `0` instead of the amount of items actually in the array

Like I can push `'Z'` and get the `Debug.Log(itemsInInv.Count)` will say `15`. Then I'll click the item to try and run the same `Debug.Log(itemsInInv.Count)` and it returns `0`.

I've tried using the built in interface on the unity program. I tried using

```
items.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { useItem(); });
```

Which actually did work 100% fine for a little while then for some reason stopped working and won't work again no matter what I do lol.

I've tried using:

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    manager.GetComponent<UIManager>().Remove(this.gameObject);
    Debug.Log("remove" + manager.GetComponent<UIManager>().itemsInInv.Count);
}
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Also tried doing the remove in the same function as the click. Same problem. Idk how else this is possible to do it? Even if I create a boolean and have it set to `false`, then use the button to set it too `true`, it won't read as `true` when debugged.

What I'm pretty much asking is, how do I add a list of buttons to the screen. Then delete the SAME button I clicked on from the screen and the list.

Comment: Where are you calling `items.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(()` from?

Comment: Its on a keyDown in my update.

Comment: Pushing a key, 
items = (GameObject)Instantiate(dagger, new Vector2(0.07514355f, -0.9026657f), new Quaternion());
then it sets and positions its parent then adds the
                items.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { useItem(); });
then adds it too the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soo this is what i did to get it too work....

i added this script onto my item thats being clicked

```
public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(gameObject);
    Debug.Log("hey"+ EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject);
}
```

then in my other script im running

```
            items.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { useItem(); });
```

which runs

```
public void useItem()
{
    Invoke("itemUsed", 0.25f);
}
```

which runs after 0.25

```
void itemUsed()
{
    Debug.Log(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject);
    deleteItem(EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject);
    sortItems();
}
```

I had to do the invoke because it was calling useItem, before the currently selected was being selected

Also my event System was a child of my canvas which made my gameManager unable to access it the way i was

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a list. Use a Dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<string, GameObject> dict = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
```

then you can use the gameobjects name.

```
foreach(GameObject r in FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)))
{
      dict.Add(r.name, r);
}
```

Then you can do

```
Destroy(gameObject.name);
dict.Remove(gameObject.name);
```

Comment: So if i do that i cant add mroe than one of anything with the same name, plus how would i use a for loop to iterate threw it for positioning of the gameObjects in the dictionary?

Comment: Use a foreach loop or Linq.

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, GameObject> d in dict) { doSomething(); } And you can still store multiple instances inside of the dictionary, just use a gameobject array in it. Dictionary<string, GameObject[]>

Comment: Hmm ok, so i did that. But how do i reference the button i clicked on. This script is not on the gameObject that's being destroyed. Its on a seperate script. 

This is on my UIManager Script along with the useItem() function.


                items.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { useItem(); });

So in my void UseItem(){} how would i reference the button i currently clicked

Comment: I tried using EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject) but it returns null

Comment: and how do i use this with a dictionary

for(var i =0; i < itemsInInv.Count; i++)
        {
            itemsInInv[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3(44 * (i % 4), -44 * (i / 4), 0f);
        }